# How to display one result each for max, min, avg using Aggregation in MongoDB with one query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So here are some questions from my homework that I'm struggling to understand:

Find out the *average*, *maximum* and *minimum* *h* and *er* per *team_id*.
Find out the *average*, *maximum* and *minimum* *h* and *er* per *team_id* and *year*.

Both are very similar however the second question also asks for the year. Im not sure how exactly to set up my query to solve these questions using aggregations. If anyone can show me a solution to one question that would greatly help as I learn from examples rather than working around it.

The data I use has the following structure; the first line being the header:

```
player_id,year,stint,team_id,league_id,w,l,g,gs,cg,sho,sv,ipouts,h,er,hr,bb,so,baopp,era,ibb,wp,hbp,bk,bfp,gf,r,sh,sf,g_idp
bechtge01,1871,1,PH1,,1,2,3,3,2,0,0,78.0,43,23,0,11,1,,7.96,,,,0,,,42,,,
brainas01,1871,1,WS3,,12,15,30,30,30,0,0,792.0,361,132,4,37,13,,4.5,,,,0,,,292,,,
fergubo01,1871,1,NY2,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,3.0,8,3,0,0,0,,27.0,,,,0,,,9,,,
fishech01,1871,1,RC1,,4,16,24,24,22,1,0,639.0,295,103,3,31,15,,4.35,,,,0,,,257,,,
fleetfr01,1871,1,NY2,,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,27.0,20,10,0,3,0,,10.0,,,,0,,,21,,,
flowedi01,1871,1,TRO,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,3.0,1,0,0,0,0,,0.0,,,,0,,,0,,,
mackde01,1871,1,RC1,,0,1,3,1,1,0,0,39.0,20,5,0,3,1,,3.46,,,,0,,,30,,,
mathebo01,1871,1,FW1,,6,11,19,19,19,1,0,507.0,261,97,5,21,17,,5.17,,,,2,,,243,,,
mcbridi01,1871,1,PH1,,18,5,25,25,25,0,0,666.0,285,113,3,40,15,,4.58,,,,0,,,223,,,
mcmuljo01,1871,1,TRO,,12,15,29,29,28,0,0,747.0,430,153,4,75,12,,5.53,,,,0,,,362,,,
```

The complete file can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/csula/cs1222-fall-2016/master/samples/pitching.csv).

Thanks to anyone that reads and helps!

Comment: It would be helpful to know that document structure(s). Also please read the article here to know how you can improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - you are more likely to receive an answer to your question.

Comment: Of course ! Heres is a link address to the database itself: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/csula/cs1222-fall-2016/master/samples/pitching.csv

Comment: Please consider to [edit] your question and  include sample document with the expected result. The link to the database will not help

Comment: @Elyasin this is not a valid BSON document.

Comment: It is not, but that is what is given. I think the SO needs to learn how to *import* this data and do queries on it. For the moment that is what is given.

Comment: @Alex_23 - This question is a bit broad I think. I suggest that you try to model and import the data into mongoDB. Once you have the document structure(s) that you can show us - we could help you with the queries. Then come back and edit your question to show what you have done so far and how the document structure(s) look like.

Comment: I apologize for any issues regarding my question I'm very new to this site and barely learning aggregations in mongodb. It would make more sense if you go to my school's github repository. Here's a link to the assignment it is question number 8 and 9: https://github.com/csula/cs1222-fall-2016/blob/master/homeworks/homework4.md          Note: All credit goes to the author/publisher of the github repository I provided none of it is my own work.

Comment: @Alex_23, sorry but this is not how SO is supposed to work. You are expected to show your work, display your efforts in the question when you are stuck and we go on from there. What you are asking is not about aggregation; it is about data modelling first and foremost. Before we can go ahead, you have to learn to get the data into the database.